# Dataset not getting created via Powershell for type=AzureSqlMITable

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Issue: error on ADF when trying to create ADF Components such as dataset for AzureSQLMITable via powershell

Analysis:

Error is reproducable on BuildServer (run via DevOps) & locally via Windows PowerShell.

Error is not reproducible in Azure Cloudshell & Powershell core with same set of commands

Error on ADF for the dataset:

> Could not load resource #datasetname. Please ensure no mistakes in the JSON and that referenced resources exist. Status: UnknownError, Possible reason: Fetch failed for named: dataset$#datasetname. Adapter not found. Type: dataset.

If manually pasted the file(jsonfile) in ADF it works as expected without error

Expected resolution: How to make it work with WindowsPowershell?

Json file:

```
{
    "name": "#datasetname",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "<connection name>",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureSqlMITable",
        "schema": [],
         "typeProperties": {

             "tableName": {
                "value": "<StoredProcedure_Name_Name>",
                "type": "Expression"
            }
        }  
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

Powershell commands:

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount

$BaseFolder=<FilePath>

$file = Get-ChildItem $BaseFolder -Recurse -Include *.json -Filter #somefilter -ErrorAction Stop

Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Dataset -DataFactoryName <datafactoryname> -Name ($file.BaseName) -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroupname> -DefinitionFile $file.FullName -Force -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: The `Get-ChildItem` returns an **array** of (in your case) .json files. Better use `-Filter '*.json'` and loop through the results

Comment: @Theo ok. But that's not the question, the question is that Dataset not getting created correctly

Comment: Because `$file.BaseName` will also result in an array instead of a single string I guess

Comment: Resolved with Az Commands using powershell core commands(via Azure Powershell task in CICD instead of Powershell script which was Windows one)

Comment: @akshayslodha Congratulations you have solved the problem. I help you post the it as the answer, you can think about accept(mark) it( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.), this can be beneficial to other community members. You also can post it by yourself with more details and I will delete the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with Az Commands using powershell core commands(via Azure Powershell task in CICD instead of Powershell script which was Windows one).

The point here is that henceforth people should use Powershell core(Az) as it will have new feature and windows powershell(AzureRm) will only have bug fixes